# Script Convert KML to Layer

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, kml, convert

I have a KML file (https://meocloud.pt/link/a60a4408-0b89-4163-9a4d-c91c181bbab4/ROI.kml/) and I want to convert to SHP in ModelBuilder using this script that I found on-line, but it doesn't work. Can you help me with that?

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
# Author: Jason Parent
# Modified By: Robert McCann
# Date: May 3, 2008
# Modified: June 6, 2008
# Purpose: Convert kml file to shapefile with feature name and description as attributes
# Modified to read kml folder and attribute to shapefile
# Modified to handle multiple features and interior polygons

import arcgisscripting, os, sys, traceback

try:
    # create geoprocessor...
    gp = arcgisscripting.create()

    gp.OverwriteOutput = 1

##    # data management toolbox...
##    management_tbx = r"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Data Management Tools.tbx"
##    
##    # check if data management toolbox is found...
##    if not gp.exists(management_tbx):
##        gp.AddError("ArcGIS Data Management Toolbox not found. Script cannot execute")
##        sys.exit(1)
##    
##    # load toolbox...
##    gp.AddToolbox (management_tbx)

# script parameters...

kmlFile = sys.argv[1]       # kml file
featureType = sys.argv[2]   # POLYGON, POLYLINE, POINT
outName = sys.argv[3]       # output file name


featureType = featureType.upper()   # convert to uppercase

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# GET FEATURE DATA FROM KML FILE...

gp.AddMessage("Extracting %s feature data from KML file..." % featureType)
print "Extracting %s feature data from KML file..." % featureType


# list for feature data...
fileDataLst = []

# open kml file...
openFile = open(kmlFile, "r")
line = openFile.readline()

#declare folder hierachy list
folderlist = []
folder = ""
# read through each line and identify lines with data...

while line:
    # If folder section exists, add it's name to folder list
    # <Folder> indicates a folder section
    if "<Folder>" in line:
        # get folder name...
        line = openFile.readline()
        if "/name" in line:
            start, end = line.find(">"), line.rfind("<")
            folderlist.append(line[start+1:end])

    # If folder section closes, remove it's value from the list
    if "</Folder>" in line:
        try:
            del folderlist[len(folderlist)-1]
        except:
            pass

    if "<Placemark>" in line:
        name = description = ""
        XYLst = []  # list for vertex coordinates

        # read line by line until the end of feature section (indicated by Placemark)
        while "/Placemark" not in line:

            # get feature type...
            if "<Polygon>" in line: feature = "POLYGON"              
            elif "<LineString>" in line: feature = "POLYLINE"           
            elif "<Point>" in line: feature = "POINT"


            # get feature name...
            if "</name>" in line:
                start, end = line.find(">"), line.rfind("<")
                name = line[start+1:end]

            # get feature description...
            if "</description>" in line:
                start, end = line.find(">"), line.rfind("<")
                description = line[start+1:end]


            # get coordinates of vertices...
            if "</coordinates>" in line:                    
                # extract coordinate section...
                end = line.rfind("<")
                line = line[:end]
                start = line.find(">")

                # if found (only found for point features)...
                if start != -1:
                    line = line[start+1:]   # extract after > symbol

                # list of XYZ strings for vertices...
                coordinateLst = line.rstrip(" </coordinates>\n").split(" ")


                # extract XY coordinates for each vertex
                if coordinateLst[0] <> '':
                    for XYZ in coordinateLst:
                        XYZ = XYZ.split(",")
                        XYLst.append([float(XYZ[0]), float(XYZ[1])])
                else:
                    XYLst = []

            # multiple linear rings means multiple features
            # insert blank into coordinate list
            if "<LinearRing>" in line:
                if XYLst:
                    XYLst.append([])

            line = openFile.readline()  # get next line

        # if feature is of specified type, add to data list...
        if feature == featureType:
            folder = '/'.join(folderlist) #join folder list to string seperated by '/'
            fileDataLst.append([name,description,XYLst,folder])

    line = openFile.readline()  # get next line

# close kml file...
openFile.close()


# number of features added to shapefile...
numFeatures = len(fileDataLst)

gp.AddMessage("Feature data acquired for %s %s features." % (numFeatures,featureType))
print "Feature data acquired for %s %s features." % (numFeatures,featureType)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CREATE NEW SHAPEFILE TO CONTAIN FEATURE(S)

if numFeatures > 0:

    gp.AddMessage("Creating shapefile")
    print "Creating shapefile"

    # geographic projection file (projection of google earth)...
    # spat_ref = r"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Coordinate Systems\Geographic Coordinate Systems\World\WGS 1984.prj"

    # factory code for GCS_WGS_1984...
    spat_ref = "4326"

    # get workspace and basename from output file name...
    outWksp = os.path.dirname(outName)
    gp.workspace = outWksp + "\\"
    basename = os.path.basename(outName)

    # create output shapefile...
##        gp.addmessage("%s" %outWksp)
##        gp.addmessage("%s" %basename)
##        gp.addmessage("%s" %featureType)
##        gp.addmessage("%s" %spat_ref)
    gp.CreateFeatureClass_management(gp.workspace, basename, featureType, "", "", "", spat_ref)

    # add name and description fields...
    gp.addfield(outName, "NAME",   "TEXT", "#", "#", "100")
    gp.addfield(outName, "DESCR",  "TEXT", "#", "#", "250")
    gp.addfield(outName, "FOLDER", "TEXT", "#", "#", "100")

    # create insert cursor and new row for output file...
    cur = gp.InsertCursor(outName)
    newRow = cur.newRow()

    cnt = 0            

    # for each feature...
    for feat in fileDataLst:

        #------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # CREATE FEATURE FROM COORDINATES AND ADD TO OUTPUT SHAPEFILE...

        name = feat[0]
        description = feat[1]
        XYLst = feat[2]
        folder = feat[3]

        if not XYLst:
            gp.AddWarning("Cannot convert feature named %s to shapefile" % name)
            continue

        # create feature object...

        # create point object...
        pnt = gp.CreateObject("point")

        # if feature is a polygon or line...
        if featureType == "POLYGON" or featureType == "POLYLINE":
            feature = gp.CreateObject("array")          # create a feature array
            part    = gp.CreateObject("array")          # create a part array

            # for each vertex...
            for XY in XYLst:
                if XY:
                    pnt.X, pnt.Y = XY[0], XY[1]         # assign point coordinates
                    part.add(pnt)                       # add point to array
                else:                                   # missing point indicates interior polygon
                    feature.add(part)
                    part.removeall()

            feature.add(part)
            del part

            newRow.Shape = feature                      # set shape property for new row

        # if feature is a point...
        else:
            pnt.X, pnt.Y = XYLst[0][0], XYLst[0][1]     # assign point coordinates
            newRow.Shape = pnt                          # set shape property for new row

        # set name and description field values...
        newRow.NAME = name
        newRow.DESCR = description
        newRow.FOLDER = folder

        # insert row into output shapefile    
        cur.InsertRow(newRow)

        cnt += 1
        if cnt % 50 == 0:                
            gp.AddMessage("Created %s %s feature" % (cnt,featureType))
            print "Created %s %s feature" % (cnt,featureType)

    # delete insert cursor and new row...
    del cur,newRow

    gp.AddMessage("KML to shapefile conversion complete")
    print "KML to shapefile conversion complete"

else:
    gp.AddWarning("No %s features found - aborting kml to shapefile conversion...\n" % (featureType))

except:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]

pymsg = tbinfo + "\n" + str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value)

gp.AddError(pymsg)

print pymsg
```

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS? Seems like you are based on the script. If thats the case, forget this script. Simply use the KML to Layer tool to convert KMZ into fgdb-featureclass.

Answer (score 2):

That script is outdated.

You can use the built in functionality of ArcGIS Desktop's ArcToolbox:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/kml-to-layer.htm

It's in the **Conversion Tools** toolbox, and then inside **From KML**.